# underscore js template if check on a variable

Tags: templates, backbone.js, web, underscore.js

i am trying to use underscore.js template method to render some data
so basically this is what i want to do if i were to do it in pseudo code

```
if (url is not null) {
     <div>
       <img src=url />
     </div>
}
```

I need to do this check in underscore js template, but I am not sure if the following is legit
the tricky part is that url is also a template variable

```
<% if (<%=url%>) { %>
    <img src=<%=url%> />
<% } %>
```

help?

Comment: Remember that the variable MUST be in the context! If you're not always providing "url" when rendering the template you have to check for typeof url !== "undefined" as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On javascript:

```
 var myTmpl = _.template(foo);
 myTmpl.tmpl({url: 'foo.com'});
```

On template:

```
<% if (url) { %>
  <img src=<%=url%> />
<% } %>
```

Remember: When you use <% you are just writing javascript ;)